# Water valve for food

Tags: hardware

I am working on a project, where i need to control the flow of a liquid made from food.

For example: making chicken curry, I will separate all the liquid from the meat, and run that tough a pipe, where this control pipe is on.

But I have been unable to find a subtle valve for this, as the liquid on all of them will flow tough the mechanics of the valve, and this would not be optimal as it would make it impossible to clean, and it would diffidently get stuck.

Can one of you suggest a valve that would work for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, instead of a valve, a [Peristaltic Pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump).

In short, it comprises a set of rollers that squeeze a flexible tube and push the fluid along. It has good advantages for food use:

- Very easy to clean - only the inside of the tube needs cleaning
- Pumped fluid is not in physical contact with the pump mechanism so can't be contaminated.

They are used in many sterile environments - medical, industrial, etc., because they are so easy to keep clean and have no way of contaminating the pumped fluid. They are also good with viscous (sticky, gloopy) fluids like soups and sauces.

They can also deliver precisely measured amounts very easily.